# Cannot install Qt-4 on Ubuntu 20.04 - Quite Universal Circuit Simulator (QUCS)

Tags: qt, qt4

System: Kubuntu-64-bit 20.04 - AMD 64-bit machine
I`m trying to install [Quite Universal Circuit Simulator](https://sourceforge.net/projects/qucs/) from source code and get error:

```
configure: error: Qt >= 4.6.0 is required.
configure: error: ./configure failed for qucs
```

Try to install Qt-4 get error:

```
apt-get install qt4-dev-tools libqt4-dev libqt4-core libqt4-gui
E: Unable to locate package qt4-dev-tools
E: Package 'libqt4-dev' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package libqt4-core
E: Unable to locate package libqt4-gui
```

How do I get this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although [@kyodake answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1274166/16395) is correct, there is good news:

1. Nice developers are working on Qt5 port in the main site;
2. I have concocted an AppImage version (alas, without manuals and probably not the best configured one, but it works) here: https://rmano.github.io/qucsAppImagesBuild/

You can just download the AppImage, make it executable with `chmod +x`, and run it.

[image]

Comment: I works!!! Thanks a lot nice developers.

Comment: Thanks! Can I suggest to add the word QUCS to the title to make it more search-friendly? @Teso

Comment: Of course I will do that, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I also have a suggestion. The icons of QUCS could be adapted to dark themes.

Comment: Yes, but... QUCS is now an almost-one-man free time effort, and the most important thing is to get the qt5 port completed. I unfortunately have no c++ skills for helping...

Comment: I would like to help but my programming skills are very limited. I hope that some nice developers will join this project.

Answer (score 12):

The Qt4 framework has been removed from Ubuntu 20.04 main repository.

You can still get Qt4 libraries, adding the PPA  rock-core/qt4

Run in a terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:rock-core/qt4

sudo apt update
```

And install the required Qt4 libraries by running command:

```
sudo apt install qt4-dev-tools libqt4-dev libqt4-core libqt4-gui
```

or

```
sudo apt install qt4-dev-tools libqt4-dev libqtcore4 libqtgui4
```

Comment: I had issues with packages libqt4-core and libqt4-gui so I used this packages - sudo apt install libqtcore4 libqtgui4

Comment: sudo add-apt-repository ppa:rock-core/qt4 does not work on ubuntu 21.04. Is there a way to add that on the latest ubuntu?