# How can I fix "Unable to locate package libvtk5-qt4-dev" on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, ppa, update-manager

I had a similar issue with qt so did this and it worked:  https://askubuntu.com/a/1274166/806813

But for this one, I could only find:  http://neuro.debian.net/install_pkg.html?p=libvtk5-qt4-dev

I get an error on update:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

```
Get:1 http://neuro.debian.net/debian data InRelease [30.2 kB]                      
Hit:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/rock-core/qt4/ubuntu focal InRelease                
Err:1 http://neuro.debian.net/debian data InRelease                                  
The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY A5D32F012649A5A9                                                   
Get:3 http://neuro.debian.net/debian focal InRelease [18.2 kB]                     
Err:3 http://neuro.debian.net/debian focal InRelease                                 
The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY A5D32F012649A5A9                                                   
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease                   
Hit:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                             
Hit:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease                  
Hit:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease                     
Hit:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease                   
Reading package lists... Done                                                      
W: GPG error: http://neuro.debian.net/debian data InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY A5D32F012649A5A9                                                                           
E: The repository 'http://neuro.debian.net/debian data InRelease' is not signed.   
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.                                                                      
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.                                                                                  
W: GPG error: http://neuro.debian.net/debian focal InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY A5D32F012649A5A9                                                                          
E: repository 'http://neuro.debian.net/debian focal InRelease' is not signed.  
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.                                                                      
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details
```

The whole list of packages I want is:

```
sudo apt-get -y install autoconf build-essential checkinstall git subversion libfaac-dev libgpac-dev libjack-jackd2-dev libmp3lame-dev libopencore-amrnb-dev libopencore-amrwb-dev librtmp-dev libsdl1.2-dev libsdl2-dev libtheora-dev libtool libvdpau-dev vdpauinfo libvdpau-va-gl1 libvorbis-dev libfdk-aac-dev libvpx-dev libx264-dev libx11-dev libxext-dev libxfixes-dev libx11-xcb-dev libdrm-dev libxcb-dri3-dev libxcb-present-dev libpciaccess-dev frei0r-plugins-dev texi2html yasm zlib1g-dev nasm libxml2-dev pkg-config vainfo qttools5-dev qttools5-dev-tools libqt5svg5-dev ladspa-sdk git cmake libsndfile1-dev libsamplerate-ocaml-dev libjack-jackd2-dev liblilv-dev libiec61883-dev libavc1394-dev libass-dev libbluray-dev libbs2b-dev libcodec2-dev libdc1394-22-dev libgme-dev libgsm1-dev libopenjp2-7-dev libopenmpt-dev libopus-dev librsvg2-dev librubberband-dev libshine-dev libsnappy-dev libsoxr-dev libssh-dev libspeex-dev libtwolame-dev libwavpack-dev libwebp-dev libx265-dev libxvidcore-dev libzmq3-dev libzvbi-dev libopenal-dev libomxil-bellagio-dev libcdio-dev libcdparanoia-dev libcdio-paranoia-dev libsdl2-dev opencl-headers ocl-icd-dev ocl-icd-opencl-dev vdpau-driver-all libvdpau-dev libvdpau-va-gl1 meson autoconf automake unzip wget doxygen libcurl4-openssl-dev libdrm-dev xorg xorg-dev openbox libx11-dev libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dev qt5-default libvtk6-dev zlib1g-dev libjpeg-dev libwebp-dev libpng-dev libtiff5-dev libopenexr-dev libgdal-dev libxvidcore-dev libopencore-amrnb-dev libopencore-amrwb-dev libv4l-dev libxine2-dev libtbb-dev libeigen3-dev python-dev python-tk pylint python-numpy python3-pip python3-dev python3-tk pylint3 python3-numpy python3-opencv python3-scipy python3-pil python3-flask python3-wheel flake8 libpython-all-dev libpython3-all-dev ant default-jdk libchromaprint-dev libgtkglext1 libgtkglext1-dev liblog4cpp5-dev libdevil-dev liblivemedia-dev v4l-utils libcpprest-dev libgflags-dev libngraph0-dev libatlas3-base libatlas-base-dev libblas-dev liblapack-dev liblapacke-dev libgoogle-glog-dev curl libtbb2 libtbb-dev libjpeg-dev libpng-dev libtiff-dev libdc1394-22-dev libvtk5-qt4-dev libqt4-dev libqt4-opengl-dev libgtkglext1 libgtkglext1-dev libmysqlclient-dev gcc-8 g++-8
```

for which right now the error is:

```
Reading package lists... Done                                                       Building dependency tree                                                            Reading state information... Done                                                   Note, selecting 'python-dev-is-python2' instead of 'python-dev'                     Note, selecting 'pylint' instead of 'pylint3'                                       E: Unable to locate package libvtk5-qt4-dev
```

Comment: Qt4 is EOL and was removed from Ubuntu in 2019 (2015 upstream was announced EOL though Debian & Ubuntu supported it until 15-Mar-2019) ; (for more details refer https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/removing-qt-4-from-ubuntu-before-the-20-04-release/12295). Any  package, if maintained, should have been ported to Qt5 (introduced 19-Dec-2012) before now

Comment: Also note Qt6 is now where all development is with Qt5 now in maintenance mode though Qt5 EOL hasn't been announced yet, so whatever reason you're wanting a *deprecated* library for should be corrected asap as it'll only get harder & more of a security risk.

Comment: @guiverc so do I replace all the 4's with 6's in my package names?  For example, libvtk5-qt5-dev`?

Comment: If you replace the qt4 with qt5/qt6 without changing the program code within so ABI/API's align; you'll just get segfaults; or risk data corruption (without any crashing).  You need to *port* the code so it uses the later API/ABI's which maybe easy (*only need a recompile*) or difficult (*if calls/interfaces involved a large change this may require parts to be re-written to suit newer method(s)*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a GPG Error. This error happens when you try to install a package from an unknown source.when you receive this error, you will not be able to update your repository.To fix this error you should import public GPG key.

The problem is mentioned in the error description:

"The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY A5D32F012649A5A9 "

Try:

> > > sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys A5D32F012649A5A9

> > > sudo apt-get update

Comment: I am still getting `Unable to locate package libvtk5-qt4-dev`

Comment: The solution was for your problem in updating your repository. please send your full error explanation and include what command has caused this error message for more clarification

Comment: What are the replacements for `libvtk5-qt4-dev libqt4-dev libqt4-opengl-dev`?