# How to install qt4-default on Ubuntu 22.04? E: Unable to locate package qt4-default

Tags: qt4

I want to compile an app and I can't install QT4. [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1274134/cannot-install-qt-4-on-ubuntu-20-04-quite-universal-circuit-simulator-qucs) doesn't work.

Comment: Qt4 is EOL and was removed from Ubuntu in 2019 (2015 upstream was announced EOL though Debian & Ubuntu supported it until 15-Mar-2019) ; (for more details refer https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/removing-qt-4-from-ubuntu-before-the-20-04-release/12295).  Any Qt4 *apps* should have been ported to a *supported* Qt as Qt4 isn't patched for security flaws.

Comment: @guiverc Can I compile keepassx 0.4 for Ubuntu 22.04 or user older version that I compiled for ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: In case of a classical amd64 look at that answer : https://askubuntu.com/a/1429104/1096136

Comment: Else, for instance for a Raspberry PI, you can compile Qt 4.8.7 by yourself, that requires the same modifications in the sources I explain on https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/147356/how-to-compile-qt-4-8-7-under-debian-bookworm-and-bullseye